# how we will calculate time difference between 90%and 95% (Aggregate Report)

Tags: performance, jmeter, stress

we  have run 3000 samples total duration time is 4 min 45 sec how is it possible 99% of requests are taking time only 1 min 20 sec and only 1 % of requests take the rest of the time

we  have run 3000 samples total duration time is 4 min 45 sec how is it possible 99% of requests are taking time only 1 min 20 sec and only 1 % of requests take the rest of the time

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **90% Line (90th Percentile)** is the value below which 90% of the samples fall. The remaining samples too at least as long as the value. This is a standard statistical measure. See, for example: [Percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) entry at Wikipedia.

As per [Request Stats Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000303837-Request-Stats-Report)

> **90% line (ms)** 90th Percentile. 90% of the samples were smaller than or equal to this time.
>
> **95% line (ms)**  95th Percentile. 95% of the samples were smaller than or equal to this time.
>
> **99% line (ms)** 99th Percentile. 99% of the samples were smaller than or equal to this time.

So if you see i.e. 1500 ms as 90% percentile it means that 90% of Samplers response time was 1500 ms or less, the remaining ones are higher.